# Flutter how to screen just list in a bottom sheet

Tags: flutter, dart

I am showing a simple list view builder in bottom sheet like this

```
showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext bc){
      return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: RichText(
                text: new TextSpan(
                  // Note: Styles for TextSpans must be explicitly defined.
                  // Child text spans will inherit styles from parent
                  style: new TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  children: <TextSpan>[
                    new TextSpan(
                        text: 'Select ',
                        style: new TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16,
                            fontFamily: 'PoppinsMedium')),
                    new TextSpan(
                        text: 'Patient',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16,
                            fontFamily: 'PoppinsRegular', color: textGreyColor)),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 13),
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.08,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.92 ,
                child: TextFormField(
                  onChanged: (value) {

                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {},
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15,
                      color: kPrimaryColor,
                      fontFamily: 'UbuntuRegular'),
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(
                    border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide:
                      const BorderSide(color: Color(0xffbdbdbd), width: 1),
                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                        const Radius.circular(10.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    enabledBorder: new OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide:
                      const BorderSide(color: Color(0xffbdbdbd), width: 1),
                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                        const Radius.circular(10.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    filled: true,
                    hintStyle: new TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xffbdbdbd), fontFamily: 'UbuntuRegular'),
                    hintText: "Search",
                    fillColor: Colors.white70,
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: const BorderSide(color: kPrimaryColor, width: 1),
                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                        const Radius.circular(10.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              child: new             ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 8,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, left: 15, right: 15),
                    child: Container(
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        // onTap: widget.onPressed,
                        onTap: () {},
                        child: Stack(children: [
                          Container(
                            width: double.infinity,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15.0),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                              border: Border.all(
                                color: kPrimaryColor,
                                width: 1.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  children: [
                                    RichText(
                                      text: new TextSpan(
                                        // Note: Styles for TextSpans must be explicitly defined.
                                        // Child text spans will inherit styles from parent
                                        style: new TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 14.0,
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                        ),
                                        children: <TextSpan>[
                                          new TextSpan(
                                              text: 'Name : ',
                                              style: new TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 13,
                                                  fontFamily: 'PoppinsMedium')),
                                          new TextSpan(
                                              text: 'Hamza Tariq',
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 13,
                                                  fontFamily: 'PoppinsRegular', color: textGreyColor)),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    RichText(
                                      text: new TextSpan(
                                        // Note: Styles for TextSpans must be explicitly defined.
                                        // Child text spans will inherit styles from parent
                                        style: new TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 14.0,
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                        ),
                                        children: <TextSpan>[
                                          new TextSpan(
                                              text: 'Contact : ',
                                              style: new TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 13,
                                                  fontFamily: 'PoppinsMedium')),
                                          new TextSpan(
                                              text: '03323789263',
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 13,
                                                  fontFamily: 'PoppinsRegular', color: textGreyColor)),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  children: [
                                    RichText(
                                      text: new TextSpan(
                                        // Note: Styles for TextSpans must be explicitly defined.
                                        // Child text spans will inherit styles from parent
                                        style: new TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 14.0,
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                        ),
                                        children: <TextSpan>[
                                          new TextSpan(
                                              text: 'Gender : ',
                                              style: new TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 13,
                                                  fontFamily: 'PoppinsMedium')),
                                          new TextSpan(
                                              text: 'Male',
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 13,
                                                  fontFamily: 'PoppinsRegular', color: textGreyColor)),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    RichText(
                                      text: new TextSpan(
                                        // Note: Styles for TextSpans must be explicitly defined.
                                        // Child text spans will inherit styles from parent
                                        style: new TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 14.0,
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                        ),
                                        children: <TextSpan>[
                                          new TextSpan(
                                              text: 'Reg Date : ',
                                              style: new TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 13,
                                                  fontFamily: 'PoppinsMedium')),
                                          new TextSpan(
                                              text: '12-MAY-2021',
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 13,
                                                  fontFamily: 'PoppinsRegular',
                                                  color: textGreyColor)),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height: 8.0),

                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  children: [
                                    RichText(
                                      text: new TextSpan(
                                        // Note: Styles for TextSpans must be explicitly defined.
                                        // Child text spans will inherit styles from parent
                                        style: new TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 14.0,
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                        ),
                                        children: <TextSpan>[
                                          new TextSpan(
                                              text: 'Patient ID : ',
                                              style: new TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 13,
                                                  fontFamily: 'PoppinsMedium')),
                                          new TextSpan(
                                              text: 'C-200',
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 13,
                                                  fontFamily: 'PoppinsRegular',
                                                  color: textGreyColor)),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),

                                    RichText(
                                      text: new TextSpan(
                                        // Note: Styles for TextSpans must be explicitly defined.
                                        // Child text spans will inherit styles from parent
                                        style: new TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 14.0,
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                        ),
                                        children: <TextSpan>[
                                          new TextSpan(
                                              text: 'Email : ',
                                              style: new TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 13,
                                                  fontFamily: 'PoppinsMedium')),
                                          new TextSpan(
                                              text: 'abc.33@hotmail.com',
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 13,
                                                  fontFamily: 'PoppinsRegular',
                                                  color: textGreyColor)),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ]),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              )
              ,
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
);
```

The issue is when i scroll the search bar and my header is also scrolling because I add SingleChildScrollView on the whole bottom sheet. What I need to do is I need to just scroll the listView not the whole content inside the bottom sheet. If I remove SingleChildScrollView from the bottom sheet it's showing an overflow error. Need to know what can I do here so I can get a scrollable listView with a sticky search bar and header.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `SingleChildScrollView` and add `Expanded` on `ListView.builder` like this:

[image]

[Dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/988d5e584f730432e0a387d6f0dfdb5f?null_safety=false) to run the code online.